# How to use wildfly-cp to create a development server on Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, wildfly, fedora

I am trying to setup a development box based on Fedora 23. I am using *Eclipse Mars* for development, and *Wildfly 8 application server*. The goal is to be able to use Eclipse and Wildfly together, using only the system-provided rpm packages.

The problem: I cannot use Wildfly from Eclipse, because the server is in `/usr/share`, and owned by `root`. This is understandable, even preferable. AFAIK I should use `wildfly-cp` to create an environment, which can be used to run Wildfly as a normal user. However, I could not manage to do so yet.

I am looking for detailed instructions how to make it work from Eclipse.